# @OneToMany @JoinTable usage with three tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistent

I have been stuck with one scenario in hibernate, i tried looking for such scenario discussion but i couldnt get so raing here for any suggestions or help,

i have three tables category , category_artical, artical.

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `category_description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `category_article` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  'category_article_status' varchar(1) NOT NULL.
  'category_article_type' varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`article_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `article_id_UNIQUE` (`article_id`),
  KEY `fk_category` (`category_id`),
  KEY `fk_article` (`article_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_article` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`article_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`)
);
```

i have entity for category,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
    public class Category {

        private long id;
        private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "CATEGORY_ARTICLE",`enter code here`
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    )
    private Set<Article> articles; 
    // other getters and setters...

/*For Article entity is */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ARTICLE")
    public class Article {
        private long id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private String keywords;
        private String content;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // other getters and setters...
```

For category_article i have no entity as i am using @jointable in category
So everything work fine till i have only two column in category_article which are category_id and article_id. But as soon as i added two more columns i am confused how to inser data in those coulmns(category_article_status and category_article_type) which are not null.

any suggestions on this.

Comment: Please do tell us where are those other 2 fields in your Java model? Because JPA simply persists what is in your classes, and you don't have them in your classes.

Comment: They are new fields in CATEGORY_ARTICLE table and so i have to find a way to insert data fro these new column. old implementation i have mentioned above. So thats my question. how to insert data in these column seeing that the old implementation directly doing JoinTable and inserting category_id and article_id with join. i think this will change the current implementation.

Comment: A "COLUMN" (in a table) is not a FIELD (in a class). And as I said ... they are NOT in your CLASSES. So put them in your classes and you can then see how they map to the tables. If they are not in the Java classes then the only way those columns could be read/written would be using "magic". There are many examples of a M-N "attributed" arrangement on the web, for example https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jpa/tree/master/many_to_many_attributed

Comment: Billy, i totally understand your point and i agree, let me give you more elaborated explanation to it. So Article table is an primary table and no records from it should be deleted. CATEGORY_ARTICLE is a logic table which binds Category with ARTICLE.so if you delete any entry in CATEGORY_ARTICLE it should delete the primarry record in Category table also but not from ARTICLE. there was no delete functionality below and now they included two more columns in CATEGORY_ARTICLE. so my current design is as shown you above. when you say add into your java i cant add to Article.java and  Category.java

Comment: @billy i have to change current design, where i have to remove jointable from category and do somthing like hadi said. so i am working on solution to map these two columns and also find a way to delete record first from CATEGORY_ARTICLE and then from Category and still not touching the Article table records as they should not be deleted. Now i have one solution as hadi mentioned but in that case while adding it persist recirds in Article table too and when you remove it removes from article table which is stictly not to be done.So i am looking towards embedded will that solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another entity for `CATEGORY_ARTICLE` like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_ARTICLE")
public class CategoryArticle{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")  
   private Category category;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")  
   private Article article; 


   // other columns 
   private Boolean categoryArticleStatus;

   private Long categoryArticleType;

}
```

and also should change `Category` and `Article`. Remove `JoinTable` from category entity and change it as bellow.

**Category**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

  //.....

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
  private Set<CategoryArticle> categoryArticleSet;
}
```

**Article**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class Article {

  //.....

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
  private Set<CategoryArticle> categoryArticleSet;

 }
```

Comment: so should i remove @jointable in category entiry ? any changes in Category entity class ?

Comment: Ok so you are saying i could not use                
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "CATEGORY_ARTICLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")

Comment: Yes, and you should define two `oneToMany` relation in `CategoryArticle` entity.

Comment: let me make these changes and see how it work. lot of changes will be required now with addition to these new columns

Comment: so while em.persist() do i need to pass only Category object or both Category and Article. because i have to insert data first in Category  and then in  CATEGORY_ARTICLE. From request i am getting Category  all couln details along with article_id.

Comment: both. `em.persist(category); em.persist(article);`

Comment: No This is not working. its populating table article too why ?it should only populate CATEGORY and then CATEGORY_ARTICLE with category_id, article_id and othet two columns.

Comment: so if i just want to insert data in CATEGORY and CATEGORY_ARTICLE  not in ARTICLE table but still want to have article_id how to do it .. please suggest